# Sending data on COM Port while receiving data on it?

Tags: serial-port, port, signal-processing

My application can send and receive data independently on COM Port (9 pin).  Now the scenario is that, the destination device while sending data can also request some data. Now, in that case my application while receiving the data from the device, would have to send the requested data as well. So the question is, is it possible conceptually to send some data while receiving data from the same COM port ?

Note: If this is not the right place to ask this question, please let me know which SO site is apt for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is. The RS232 is a full duplex interface, hence there are two independent channels for each direction.

But note that these two channels are different pins of course. You cant send and receive on the same pin with the RS232 (Although it is theoretically possible to transmit and receive data over a single line simultaneously - but not in this case).

Comment: ok, but my application crashes when I try to do so simultaneously.  Any idea what could be the problem

Comment: Well, I guess it is a bug in your program.